# jQuery Memory Game

Tags: jquery, match

I am creating a Memory Game based on aditia rahman jQuery Memory Game http://superdit.com/2011/02/09/jquery-memory-game/. I have changed my version on the slight by dynamically adding the images to matched in the div tags with a unique id using jQuery rather than manually doing so. There are two problem:

1.) When I click on a card it does not "open" or flip over to reveal itself in order to find a matching card / image.

2.) While testing in Firebug I noticed that the cards / images are always in the same position and not randomly placed. For example, div id="1" contains image id="01" and following that is div id="2 containing image id="02", which will make the game dull and too easy, instead div id=1" containing image id="01" should have a random number follow such as div id="9" image id="09" to make the game more challenging each time the user plays or resets the game.

This is the jQuery script to dynamically load images and give each image an id with clone

```
var boxopend     =     "",
    imgopend     =     "",
    count        =      0,
    found        =      0,
    children     =     $("boxcard").children(),
    child        =     $("boxcard div:first-child");

var divs = $('div');

divs.each(function(i){
    //goes through each div and add unique id attribute e.g card1 - card12
    $(this).attr("id", "card" + i);

    //creates images and gives unique src, and alt attribute and then appends
    //to corresponding div  
    var img = $("<img />");
    img.attr({
        //"id": i,
        "src": "img/" + i + ".png",
        "alt": "image" + i,
});
    $(this).append(img);
});

$(divs.clone()).each(function(i){
    var divNew = $('<div></div>').insertAfter($('div:last-child'));
    divNew.attr("id", "card" + i + "00");

var img = $("<img />");
    img.attr({
        //"id": i,
        "src": "img/" + i + ".png",
        "alt": "image" + i,
});
    divNew.append(img);
});
```

This is the tutorial script which I am trying to get to work with the script above

```
function randomFromTo(from, to){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
    };

    function shuffle(){
        var array_img = new Array();
        for (i=0; i array_img[i] = $("#" +child.attr("id") + "img").attr("src");
        child = child.next();
    }

    for(z = 0; z randIndex = randomFromTo(0, array_img.length - 1);

    //set new image

    $("#"+child.attr("id")+"img").attr("src", array_img[randIndex]);
    array_img.splice(randIndex, 1);

    child = child.next();

    function openCard(){

        id = $(this).attr("id");

        if($("#"+id+"img").is(:"hidden")){
            $("#boxcard div").unbind("click", openCard);

            $("#"+id+"img").slideDown('fast');

            if(imgopened == ""){
                boxopened = id;
                imgopened = $("#"+id+"img").attr("src");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#boxcard div").bind("click", openCard)
                }, 300);
            }else{
                currentopened = $("#"+id+"img").attr("src");
                if(imgopened != currentopened){
                    //close again
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $("#"+id+"img").slideUp("fast");
                        $("#"+boxopened+"img").slideUp("fast");
                        boxopened = "";
                        imgopened = ""
                    }, 400);
                }else{
                    //found
                    $("#"+ id + "img").addClass("opacity");
                    $("#" + boxopened + "img").addClass("opacity");
                    found++;
                    boxopened = "";
                    imgopened = "";
                }

                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#boxcard id").bind("click", openCard)
                }, 400);
            }

            count++;
            $("#count").html("" + count);

            if(found == 10){
                msg ='<span id="msg">Congrats ! You Found All Shoes With 
                </span>';

                $("span.link").prepend(msg);
            }
        }   
    }
})();
```

and Finally the HTML

```
<section id="boxbutton">

       <span class="link">
            <span id="count">0</span>
       </span>
      </section>
        <section id="boxcard">
            <div><!--<img src="img/0.png" alt="image0"/>--></div>
            <div><!--<img src="img/1.png" alt="image1"/>--></div> 
            <div><!--<img src="img/2.png" alt="image2"/>--></div> 
            <div><!--<img src="img/3.png" alt="image3"/>--></div> 
            <div><!--<img src="img/4.png" alt="image4"/>--></div> 
            <div><!--<img src="img/5.png" alt="image5"/>--></div> 
            <div><!--<img src="img/6.png" alt="image6"/>--></div> 
            <div><!--<img src="img/7.png" alt="image7"/>--></div> 
            <div><!--<img src="img/8.png" alt="image8"/>--></div> 
            <div><!--<img src="img/9.png" alt="image9"/>--></div> 
            <div><!--<img src="img/10.png" alt="image10"/>--></div>
            <div><!--<img src="img/11.png" alt="image11"/>--></div>
            <div><!--<img src="img/12.png" alt="image12"/>--></div> 
         </ul>
        </section>
```

Comment: id selectors that start with numbers don't work, you could prepend them with words like `img_id` etc. more here: http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Comment: I'm not noticing `openCard()` being called anywhere.

Comment: @martincarlin87 I'm sorry the name convention for my id's start with card followed by a number (e.g card09). Sorry for the confusing wording.

Comment: @PatrickQ isn't $("#boxcard div").unbind("click", openCard); which should be $("#boxcard div").off("click", openCard); a call to openCard()? The tutorial originally had $("#boxcard div").unbind(openCard); and I updated it to the code above. Is this correct?

Comment: No, that is not a call to the function. That is saying "no longer fire the `openCard` function on click of this element". If you look at line 45 of the example, you'll see where they're binding the function to a click. That being said, that tutorial/guide/whatever is a few years old now and likely is using outdated jQuery.

Comment: Yeah the tutorial is 2-3 years old so I am trying to update the code. Would something like $("#boxcard div").on("click", function(){ openCard() }); work as a replacement to the tutorials original code $("#boxcard div").bind(openCard)? @PatrickQ

Comment: Assuming that you put that _outside_ of the `openCard` function, yes, it would work in the sense that it would trigger a call to `openCard()` upon click of any elements that match that selector. As to whether or not the function itself will do what you want without any changes, I really can't say.

Comment: ah, ok. I thought they were just numbers.